# How can you add a static filter criteria along with a user selected criteria to filter a table in Power BI?

Tags: filter, powerbi

I have a filter visual on my dashboard with dates that controls a table. What I'm looking for is if the user selects any date from the filter visual, I want the table to show data from the selected date AND a static date that I define say Dec 31, 2020. So, no matter what date the user selects, the table will always show data from Dec 31, 2020 and the selected date.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Single Select = IF(HASONEFILTER(ValueTable[TransDate]), SUM(ValueTable[Value]),0)+ CALCULATE( SUM(ValueTable[Value]), ValueTable[TransDate]=DATE(2020,12,31))

Multi Select = IF(ISFILTERED(ValueTable[TransDate]), SUM(ValueTable[Value]),0)+ CALCULATE( SUM(ValueTable[Value]), ValueTable[TransDate]=DATE(2020,12,31))